# C# Extension method to filter list

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, extension-methods

I found following extension method to filter list. I am very new to this hence I wanted to check if someone can help me. This method compare exact values but I want to use contains instead of exact compare. Any thoughts

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> FilterByProperty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source,string property,object value)
    {
        var propertyInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(property);
        return source.Where(p => propertyInfo.GetValue(p, null) == value);
    }
```

Comment: Why not just use the `Where` clause? `list.Where(c => c.MyProperty == "someValue");`

Comment: MyProperty is fixed, i want to make it dynamic..

Comment: I don't think you can assume `Contains` is defined for `Object` :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the equals `==` into `Contains`. try this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FilterByProperty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source,string property,object value)
    {
        var propertyInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(property);
        return source.Where(p => propertyInfo
                                      .GetValue(p, null)
                                      .ToString() //be aware that this might be null
                                      .Contains(value));
    }
```